# Ensure that the whole string is received from Arduino over bluetooth

Tags: android, bluetooth, arduino, app-inventor

In App Inventor, how do I make sure that the whole string is received?

I'm continuously sending text commands between Arduino and an Android app. I'm using  a function on Arduino that makes sure that the whole command arrived before processing it further:

(Credit: [@Robin2](http://forum.arduino.cc/index.php?topic=288234.msg2016582#msg2016582))

```
const byte numChars = 32;
char receivedChars[numChars];
boolean newData = false;

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(38400);
}

void loop() {
  read_serial();
}

void read_serial() {
  static boolean recvInProgress = false;
  static byte ndx = 0;
  char startMarker = '<';
  char endMarker = '>';
  char rc;
  while (Serial.available() > 0 && newData == false) {
    rc = Serial.read();
    if (recvInProgress == true) {
      if (rc != endMarker) {
        receivedChars[ndx] = rc;
        ndx++;
        if (ndx >= numChars) {
          ndx = numChars - 1;
        }
      } else {
        receivedChars[ndx] = '\0'; // terminate the string
        recvInProgress = false;
        ndx = 0;
        newData = true;
        char * strtokIndx;
        strtokIndx = strtok(receivedChars, ":");
        int section = atoi(strtokIndx);
        strtokIndx = strtok(NULL, ":");
        int action = atoi(strtokIndx);
        strtokIndx = strtok(NULL, ":");
        int value = atoi(strtokIndx);
        do_something_with(section, action, value);
      }
    } else if (rc == startMarker) {
      recvInProgress = true;
    }
  }
}
```

Now, how to replicate this functionality in App Inventor, to make sure that the Clock timer will not split my text commands into parts?

App Inventor (clock at 100 ms):

[image]

---

Example:

Arduino (this part fires often):

```
my_function(){
  Serial.print(NUMBER);
  Serial.print(":");
  Serial.print(ANOTHER_NUMBER);
  Serial.print(":");
  Serial.println(YET_ANOTHER_NUMBER);
}
```

And the test output in my Android app:

> - 1:3:150
> - 1:3:150
> - 1:3:150
> - 1:3:1
> - 50
> - 1:3:150
> - ...

As you can see, the 4th command has been split into parts. How do I prevent this?

Comment: you might want to ask in the [App Inventor forum](https://groups.google.com/forum/?utm_medium=email&utm_source=footer#!forum/mitappinventortest)...

Answer (score 1):

Finally, designed working solution.

The idea is to send text pattern commands: `<` start `command` end `>`

then in App Inventor:

- set `BTCommand` variable as empty string
- update `BTCommand` every time a new bits comming
- call function which checks wheather `<` and `>` exists in `BTCommand` string
- split `BTCommand` string into commands
- call commands and remove them from `BTCommand` string
- if anything left - `<com`, keep it in the `BTCommand` string, wait for `mand>`, and call it next time.

[image]

---

[Worth to read](https://arduinoplusplus.wordpress.com/2017/05/10/reliable-bluetooth-data-transfer-between-arduino-and-mit-app-inventor-ai2/)